# Pandas row values to columns, and then 1 or 0 if that was the value in the row or not

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A little confused about how to approach this as I'm new to Pandas.

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
Col1 Col2
Val1 100
Val2 150
Val3 200
```

And what I'd like to get is this

```
Val1 Val2 Val3 Col2
1    0    0    100
0    1    0    150
0    0    1    200
```

So if the value existed at that row, it should be a 1 in its new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_dummies`

```
In [5696]: pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
Out[5696]:
   Col2  Val1  Val2  Val3
0   100     1     0     0
1   150     0     1     0
2   200     0     0     1
```

Or,

```
In [5701]: df.Col1.str.get_dummies().join(df['Col2']) 
           # or df[['Col2']].join(df.Col1.str.get_dummies())
Out[5701]:
   Val1  Val2  Val3  Col2
0     1     0     0   100
1     0     1     0   150
2     0     0     1   200
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to convert the numbers to strings and then loop through them, checking if each character is '0' or not. I have to run right now but I'll edit this post with the code later today. sry

Comment: reminder to add the code you promised, otherwise this isn't really a high quality answer

Answer (score 0):

By using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.col2,df.col1).reset_index()
```